# Помогите улучшить решение задачи

Tags: c++, c

Есть задача

```
Дана последовательность положительных целых чисел, завершающаяся числом 0. Определите сумму элементов этой последовательности.

При решении этой задачи нельзя использовать массивы.
Общее количество чисел во входных данных не превосходит 2*10^6.
```

И вот такой код

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
 
int main()
{
  int a, b = 0;
  while(cin){
    cin >> a;
    b += a;
    if(a == 0){
      break;
    }
  }
cout << b;
  
}
```

На одном из тестов переполняется память(Memory limit). Как я могу это исправить?

Comment: Не знаю за "переполнение памяти", но у вас тут не верно выполнена проверка: у вас после попытки ввода вместо проверки состояния cin идет сложение, а проверка выполняется только в начале следующей итерации. Это может привести к непридвиденным последствиям

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch т.е. проверку выполнять до сложения?

Comment: очевидно же: как вы гарантируете что там значение, а не какой-то мусор

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch после вашего совета прога прошла 23 теста(до этого 3). И опять memory limit))

Comment: я не знаю что за мемори лимит, что он означает и откуда вы его берете, так что с этим я (да и кто угодно) вряд ли помогу

Comment: Так может просто сумма двух миллионов положительных целых чисел не влезает в `int`. Используйте для суммы `unsigned long long` ну и для ввода числа попробуйте `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 1):

Когда у вас есть до двух миллионов положительных чисел, то сумма этих элементов вполне может не вмещаться в `int`, тем более, что этот тип тут вообще неуместен.  Так как все числа положительные,  уместен без знаковый тип(например unsigned int), а их сумма должна вмещаться в тип объекта, хранящий эту сумму, и скорее тут уместен unsigned long long. Так что ваш код с улучшениями может выглядеть:

```
unsigned n;
unsigned long long sum{};
while (std::cin >> n && n)
    sum += n;
std::cout << sum;
```